# How can I pass the "No Looking" challenge?

Tags: rogue-legacy

While exploring the castle, sometimes a Fairy Chest can be found randomly. Each one of these have a different challenge to pass to let you loot them. Most are fairly self-explanatory, with the exception of the "No Looking" objective.

[image]

I've understood that I have to get to the chest without looking at it, but how?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This are the steps to do this challenge:

1. Face the opposite direction then the chest and jump up.
2. **a)** Press the **`attack`** button and then quickly press **`back`**. Repeat untill you reach the chest then open it

   **b)** Keep pressing the button for dashing to the right. You will dash right without turning around (Dash rune required!).

Note that:

- You have to press **`back`** right after **`attack`** and that if you hold **`back`** button for too long your character will change direction and face the chest which will make you fail the objective
- You can't do this if you have **Flexible** Trait because that trait makes you turn around when trying this method

Comment: I think it's now the Flexible trait that turns you around when attacking.

Comment: No idea, I stopped playing Rogue Legacy ages ago. If anyone can confirm that they changed which trait makes you turn around let me know and I'll change my post, or someone who has enough rep points can change the post himself I wont mind.

Comment: http://rogue-legacy.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Traits says, "Flexible: The hero can turn mid-swing to redirect their attack."  There is no E.D.S. on that page.  I'll put in the edit.

Answer (score 23):

An easier way, if you have the Dash rune, is to face to the left but press the button to dash to the right. You'll dash right without actually turning to face that direction.

Comment: Oh really? Mind if i add that to my answer? Btw does dash eats any mana or is it free to use?

Comment: Go ahead. Dash is free.

Answer (score 1):

Look away and attack. While you are attacking you can move a short ways without changing direction. Repeat a few times to reach the chest